# List linux Drivers using Regex

Tags: regex, linux, drivers

I want to list all my drivers from  the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

my file looks like this:

```
section "input class"
        identifier    "blablabla"
        driver        "my driver here"
```

I want to list every driver in this file using regex. I thought I could use something like this : `grep -i "driver"` and concat it with the pipe and then, find what is between `""`

but this is not working `grep -i "driver" | grep -i "\"(.*?)\""`

I think the problem is whitespaces but how could I use `[[:space:]]` to ignore them ?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but something that I can quickly think of:

```
grep driver /etc/X11/xorg.conf  | cut -d '"'  -f 2
```

The `grep` command would list all lines containing the pattern `driver`. The `-d` argument to cut specifies the delimiter, and the `-f` specifies the fields you want to print

You could do the same using `awk` in a single command:

```
awk -F '"' -v PATTERN="driver" '$0 ~ PATTERN { print $2 }' /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: Oh I see, its working but is there any other ways to get the same reuslt without using cut ? im not familiar with the cut command assuming that im learning GNU.